# How to improve localhost socket speed under Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, localhost

I am writing a network library (blocking sockets) for transporting multiple unpacked images (maximum 4096x4096x4 = ~67MB) from a central image server to one or multiple instances of a 3d program, which uses these as textures. Main scenario is localhost only. As the data can become pretty big, I of course am interested in the best possible network speed especially on localhost.

I already use the [SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH localhost optimization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj841212(v=vs.85).aspx), which boosts the speed a lot.

I wrote a single thread/single socket speed test client+server, which sends 100 GiB over localhost, and which I optimized until I reached ~96% processing both for `send()` and `recv()`.

This program shows me:

- ~4.6GiB/s for very large chunks/buffer (1GiB)
- ~3.5GiB/s for large chunks (100MiB)
- ~1.6GiB/s for smaller chunks (10MiB)

So far so good, now comes the funny part:

If I start 5 instances of each client + server, the speed per instance lowers a bit, but overall it's much higher:

- Avrg. ~2.6GiB/s * 5 = 13GiB/s for 1GiB chunks
- Avrg. ~1.8GiB/s * 5 = 9GiB/s for 100MiB chunks
- Avrg. ~1.4GiB/s * 5 = 7GiB/s for 10MiB chunks

So now I'm asking myself what causes this. I think I can exclude the processing of my own test programs since both server and client stay 96% in `send()` and `recv()`. So only the socket transport itself stays as the reason.

Is the socket implementation in Windows itself single-threaded? Will non-blocking/overlapped sockets improve speed in `send()` and `recv()`? Or is it more advisable to split the data into multiple threads, chunks and multiple sockets per connection? Or are there any other optimization options I didn't think of?

Comment: You need more information, recommend you look at _xperf_.  Basic Google search should get you started. Also see: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/xperf/

Comment: How many cores? Does the performance still improve with more threads than cores?